# How to transform the XML structure using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT but not to XML.I need to transform this structure

```
<Data>
<Details>Good
Bad
Normal
</Details>
<Grade>A
B
</Grade>
<Age>50
60
</Age>
</Data>
```

Values inside Details, Grade and Age tag are separated(delimiter) using CRLF.

into

```
 <PersonDetails>
    <Details>
       <Type>Good</Type>
       <Grade>A</Grade>
       <Age>50</Age>
    </Details>
    <Details>
       <Type>Bad</Type>
       <Grade>B</Grade>
       <Age>60</Age>
    </Details>
    <Details>
       <Type>Normal</Type>
       <Grade></Grade>
       <Age></Age>
    </Details>
  </PersonDetails>
```

I came to know that there is no split() function and we need to use recursive template to split the strings but am not able to wrap my head to create the required output.

Am using .net so XSLT 2.0 is not supported.I know we can use other processor like saxon, but I would like to create it using XSLT 1.0.

Or if it is any other way I will consider that too.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? This does have a "tokenize" function, which could be used to split the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a nice solution, but more to show that (an how) it is also possible with XSLT 1.0  even without any extension.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <PersonDetails>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Details" />
        </PersonDetails>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Details">

        <xsl:call-template name="genDetails">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="3" />
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name ="genDetails">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="char" select="'&#10;'" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$text != '' ">

                <Details>

                    <Type>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $char))"/>
                    </Type>
                    <Grade>
                        <xsl:call-template name="gettext">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="../Grade" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$count" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </Grade>
                    <Age>
                        <xsl:call-template name="gettext">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="../Age" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$count" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </Age>
                </Details>
                <xsl:if test="contains($text, $char)">
                    <xsl:call-template name="genDetails">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $char)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count  + 1" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text><!-- empty text --></xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name ="gettext">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="char" select="'&#13;'" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$count = $pos">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $char))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $char)">
                <xsl:call-template name="gettext">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $char)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count  + 1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char" />
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text><!-- empty text --></xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I would appreciate how 'gettext' template works because I don't want to blindly copy the answer.Thank you.

Comment: Which part do you have problems to understand?

Comment: In 'gettext' template, can you explain how $count and $pos value is updated.And say if there is no data under details tag then it is not printing the values of grade and age.

Comment: gettext  is a modified recursive tokenizer. . In each next step count is $count  + 1. pos is only past to the next step. text is than the text behind the next newline char. The recursion terminates if there are no newlines anymore or if count==pos. And yes it will only output as much grade and age elements  as lines in details. But should also work with empty lines.

Comment: Hey just need some more help ,because now the data is coming from web service and now I need to find out which element has number of highest lines and generate that many details.For example say now age can have 4 lines and grade and details can have 2 lines, so I need to generate 4 details.

Comment: I can identify which elements has highest lines based on the delimiter, but can't generate that many child element.

Comment: I can use if-else but I don't want to repeat the code and the data is dynamic and not fixed and element can have highes lines.Thank you.

Comment: First of all consider to accept the answer if you initial question was answered. Then try to change genDetails that do not stop recursion if text is empty, but if a maxcount is reached (es in gettext). When this is done call genDetails with the number of lines.  If this does not help please ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry was out of town and will accept the answer.Thank you very much.It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move to an XSLT 2.0 processor then make use of existing libraries like EXSLT http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl exsl str">

  <xsl:import href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <PersonDetails>
      <xsl:variable name="det-rtf">
        <xsl:call-template name="str:tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Details"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="det" select="exsl:node-set($det-rtf)/token[normalize-space()]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="grade-rtf">
        <xsl:call-template name="str:tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Grade"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="grade" select="exsl:node-set($grade-rtf)/token[normalize-space()]"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="$det">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <Details>
          <Type>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
          </Type>
          <Grade>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($grade[$pos])"/>
          </Grade>
        </Details>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </PersonDetails>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The computation of the `Age` elements is left as an exercise to you.